# How do I get Heroku not to insist my local Git repository is 'behind' and demand a merge?

Tags: git, heroku

I am still trying to understand how it happened, but here is the issue.

I have an app.  There is a master repository on GitHub, and some people working with me have cloned that.  I did the same on two computers of my own.  I use Heroku to have a 'shareable' prototype everyone can look at (I am doing the deep-down coding and functionality; the others are working on a lot of the UI, etc.).

I just made some changes, and tried to do the standard 'push' to Heroku.  It rejected it, saying my local repository was behind and needed to be updated.  |But when I look at what it thinks is 'ahead', it is out of date code.

I haven't yet figured out how this happened, but I suspect I was using my computer i use rarely the last time I did a push to Heroku.  I suspect I also had not done a push to the master repository 'origin', then switched computers.  Along the way, we have all added a lot of code, and what probably happened was that the few commits Heroku knows about that don't appear in the master branch anywhere got solved through new code on computers other than the one I did those few changes on. In other words, I think none of this would have occurred had I, a few months ago on the computer I use rarely, first did a 'git push origin master' the 'git push heroku master', but I didn't and it's all water under the bridge: my current master branch, locally and on the shared repository, has the core we need/want.

I tried accepting Heroku's demand that I do a 'git pull' to merge it all nicely, but for reasons you might imagine it leads to lots of conflicts (obviously, among us, we wrote new code that fixed the gaps from the few lost commits, and rearranged directory structures, so it is a huge merge conflict that it wants me to resolve.)

The question is this: How do I insist Heroku 'forget' about the git repository it has, and simply accept a fresh push of the master branch to it without having to build the whole Heroku app from scratch again?

Comment: This isn't a Heroku issue. You need to learn how Git works (it sounds like your local repository _is_ behind), and / or identify a Git workflow that fits your project, factoring in the many users, then stick with it. There are many popular Git workflows, most of which will solve your problem.

Comment: It is a Heroku issue to the degree that the Git repository in Heroku isn't fully exposed; you can't just, for example, issue a git command with a 'force' modifier.  All I want is for Heroku to clone a new repository for this app, without my needing to do the whole work that would go into setting up a new postgresql database and other work it would take.

Comment: "you can't just, for example, issue a git command with a 'force' modifier"—are you saying `git push --force-with-lease` won't work with Heroku? In fact, it will.

Comment: correct, it turns out, you are.  Where I was getting confused is that Heroku creates a herokulaunch.sh, which has as its first command 'git push heroku master', so I never quite understood even where the git repository was or that it could be manipulated directly.  'git push --force' did the trick.  What, may I ask, is 'force-with-lease'?

Comment: There are lots of resources discussing `--force` vs. `--force-with-lease`. For example, my search turned up this article: https://developer.atlassian.com/blog/2015/04/force-with-lease/

Answer (score 3):

You can do `git push --force heroku master` to reset the Heroku repo version of the "master" branch repo to be the same as your local one.

This command is destructive for the server, so it's better to first figure out what is different (i.e. why you can't do a fast-forward push). For example you suggest that it created a new file `herokulaunch.sh` that is only in the Heroku's repo and not in yours.

To figure out what's different you can do `git log heroku/master` and observe it to see if there are any useful commits that you don't have locally. If there's something you want to keep (for example commit with SHA *abc123*), you can use `git cherry-pick abc123` to take that commit locally. When it's all good, you can force push.

As a good measure you should also backup that Heroku branch for future investigations before force pushing. This is as easy as `git branch heroku-conflict heroku/master`.